# Only allow logged in/current users to edit their own post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of post in which users log into the application and can post an item. Ideally, I would like to have users edit only their post and no one else's. So far, I have it so that users are able to edit posts, but also edit others.

This is what I think I need to get fixed from index.html.erb file:

```
<td><%= review.review %> (<% if current_user%><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_review_path(review)%><%end%>)</td>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking `current_user` to the instance @user in your controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.id == @review.user_id %>
```

Which is saying, check if the user is already logged, and check if the `current_user` is the owner of the `review`, checking the `current_user` id and the `id` from the owner of such review.

So you can try:

```
<td>
  <%= review.review %>
  <% if user_signed_in && current_user.id == review.user_id %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_review_path(review) %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

You can also create a method an use it as `before_action` to check for the match between the `current_user` and the owner of the `review`, but I think the view "validation" could be enough.